# Installation problems XLConnect package on MacOS

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

Unsuccesfully I've been trying to use XLConnect on R (and Rstudio). Apparently XLConnect, XLConnectJars and rJava are installed but when loading the following error appears:

```
library(XLConnect)
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'XLConnectJars':
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Users/JorgeEd/Library/R/3.4/library
/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
dlopen(/Users/JorgeEd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library
not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/JorgeEd/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package 'XLConnectJars' could not be loaded
```

Similar errors appear when trying to load `XLConnect` or `rJava`

Any ideas?

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

OS X - 10.11.6

java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you recently installed/updated *java*? Perhaps run `R CMD javareconf` from the console and try again

Comment: What happens when you enter `echo $JAVA_HOME` in a terminal window?